# Is it possible to store a unique URL to a var after window.open has been fired?

Tags: javascript, url, window, chat, store

I'm trying to set up a video chat tool for my website and I was wanting to know if it was at all possible to store a URL on window.open due to the fact that after a specific URL link opens, it creates a unique URL that specifies a hangout. I want to store that unique hangout URL to a var and when a mobile device is detected it opens that unique URL instead of the main link.

```
 handler : function(b, e) {
            if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                window.open('pathname' || 'x');
            } else {
                window.open('https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts?gid=10820338402');
                var pathname = window.open.location.pathname;
                var x = $(location).attr('<href>');
                console.log(pathname);
                console.log(x);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the popup going to be in the same domain as opener? Looks like it isn't

Comment: I'm not too sure on that. The popup opens up in a new tab, then after loading the link, it creates a unique session ID as a URL and I want any mobile users to be able to connect to that session with that redirected link, after the desktop link is clicked. If that makes any sense

Comment: I think you might be out of luck unless you also control that page with unique ID. Otherwise cross-domain communications between windows aren't allowed and your opener cannot read popup's current URL

Comment: Well that stinks. Would there be any other way of achieving the same goal with a different process or approach?